# How to compute matrix exponential with infinite-dimensional matrices

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, matrix-exponential

I have 3 operators $A$, $B$ and $C$ that can be combined to yield the SU(2) commutation relations:

\begin{align}
\frac12(C+C^\dagger)\approx X\\
\frac{1}{2i}(C-C^\dagger)\approx Y\\
\frac12(A-B)\approx Z
\end{align}
with
\begin{align}
[X,Y]=2iZ\\
[Y,Z]=2iX\\
[Z,X]=2iY
\end{align}

I'm trying to find a computationally efficient way to compute the matrix elements of $$\exp(aA + bB +cC +dC^\dagger)$$ when $A$, $B$ and $C$ are given as infinite-dimensional matrices.

How can I exploit the correspondence with the algebra of SU(2) to compute the exponential?

Comment: Does the Zassenhaus expansion help?

Comment: Yes in fact I'm trying to use exactly that, but I don't know if I'm allowed to use finite-dimensional realizations